# Insert concatenated values from multiple rows as new row in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table with columns for "field_type" (username, city, state), "user_id", and "value".  The user_id column obviously has lots of repeats. I'd like to merge the city and state data into a single "location" field_type value.  I need something that will:

`for every integer in the user_id column:
-check if there exist corresponding (not null) table rows for field_type "city" and "state" 
-if yes, insert a new row into the table with field_type "location" which concatenates the corresponding city and state values for that user_id`

I haven't worked with MySQL much so I don't really know where to start.  I've tried to simplify the problem a bit - it's actually a somewhat more complicated wordpress table and I'm trying to reformat the data to be compatible with a new plugin, but this covers the basics of what has to happen so I should hopefully be able to extrapolate an actual solution from the answers.  Thanks for any pointers!

Edit: Current structure looks like this:

`|-id (key)-|- field_type -|- user_id -|- value -|
|    1     |  username    |     1     |  Joe    |
|    2     |  city        |     1     |  Albany |
|    3     |  state       |     1     |  NY     |
|    4     |  username    |     2     |  Bob    |
|    5     |  city        |     2     |  Toledo |
|    6     |  state       |     2     |  OH     |`

And I would like to get something like this:

`|-id (key)-|- field_type -|- user_id -|- value ---------|
|    1     |  username    |     1     |  Joe            |
|    2     |  city        |     1     |  Albany         |
|    3     |  state       |     1     |  NY             |
|    4     |  username    |     2     |  Bob            |
|    5     |  city        |     2     |  Toledo         |
|    6     |  state       |     2     |  OH             |
|    7     |  location    |     1     |  Albany, NY     |
|    8     |  location    |     2     |  Toledo, OH     |`

Duplicate user_id values are how it's supposed to work, so they don't need to be removed.

Comment: Can you please post of the schema definition of the table for more clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `INSERT ... SELECT` query to do this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
SELECT 'location' AS field_type, t1.user_id, CONCAT(t1.value, ' ', t2.value) AS value
FROM yourtable t1
JOIN yourtable t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t1.field_type = 'city' AND t2.field_type = 'state'
WHERE t1.value IS NOT NULL AND t2.value IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1b4bfd519bfc486b3ab2f9bf962e763b)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioned that there are duplicates with the same user_id.
I don't think inserting a new row will be a good idea.
So have written an update query to update the existing data.
You can later cleanup the duplciates.

```
UPDATE your_table SET locations = CONCAT_WS('-', state, city) where city is not null or state is not null
```

Comment: There are no columns in the table called `locations`, `city`, or `state`; there are only `field_type`, `user_id` and `value`. This query cannot possibly work.

Comment: Can you please post of the schema definition of the table for more clarity?

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand it from the question. Can you update it like:

Table: 
user_id(int),
city(string)

Comment: I updated the question to clarify.  Duplicates are intentional, and as Nick said I tried to explain the column in my original phrasing.

Comment: Oh, thank you, now it is much clearer, will think about it.